# f#/.net read Excel: use ApplicationClass

Tags: c#, .net, f#

If I use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass` to read an excel file as below, do I need to explictly close/quit the `Excel.applicationClass`? 
like

```
let xlsread fileName =      
   let app = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass(Visible = false)
   let book = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
   ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked an old code of mine, using Interop of Excel 2003, `ApplicationClass` does have a member called `Quit`. If you still don't find it, go to MSDN and check for the specific version of Office you use (it might differ between versions).

Comment: thanks,I missed the `Quit` method. do I need to explictly call it in the function above? or it will be automatically closed?

Comment: This the the template you should use for such interop: http://pastebin.com/LH1h5RJQ

Answer (score 0):

Using 2007 here:

```
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll"

let xlsread fileName =      
   let app = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass(Visible = false)
   let book = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName)

   do book.Close()
   do app.Quit()
```

works fine

Comment: Though just calling app.Quit seems to not destroy the spawned process, Ramon Snir' template works flawlessly.